# Phonegap Offline Database (Across all platforms)

Tags: sqlite, cordova, local-storage, windows-phone

I have gone through the [Phone Gap Storage](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html). But this is not supported on windows phones. Now I want to create a app which will be truly compatible across all platforms. i.e. windows 8 ,windows 7, windows xp, iOS, Android.

Is there a plugin or alternative to sqlite on windows phone? I have found this [Sql client for windows](http://sqlitewindowsphone.codeplex.com/releases). What's a better solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I have looked for a xplat database solution for a while as well but haven't found anything other that SQLite.  Short of utilizing XML files, SQLite still appears to be the best choice for xplat mobile phone support.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, HTML5's storage API is still in discussion, the possible solutions are either storage objects (local/session storage) or Indexed DB. Its is not yet standardized. So, no possible solution yet, but you can use a plugin compatible on major platforms you want to deploy on.

YOu can use [IOS plugin](https://github.com/brodyspark/PhoneGap-SQLitePlugin-iOS), 
[Windows 8 plugin](https://github.com/marcucio/Cordova-WP-SqlitePlugin),[Android plugin](https://github.com/brodyspark/PhoneGap-SQLitePlugin-Android)
by brodyspark. These are well documented and may solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

A cordova 3 plugin implementing Web SQL Database for WP7 and WP8 is available at https://github.com/Smile-SA/cordova-plugin-websqldatabase. This plugin is based on the "Sql client for windows" with some modifications for bugfix (the fork is available on the same git repository).

A prototype for demonstration is available at https://github.com/Smile-SA/cordova-plugin-websqldatabase-proto.

As Web SQL Database is available for iOS and Android, with this plugin you could write once and be compatible with iOS, Android and WP7 / WP8.